# Движущиеся элементы при скролле страницы - как реализовать?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всем привет!

Друзья, подскажите каким образом реализуются движущиеся элементы при скролле страницы?

Например, как здесь http://beta.yandex.ru/ 
Под видео есть человек. Когда он попадает на экран, он начинает двигаться вместе с страницами к центру.

Спасибо.

Comment: [демка - универсальный ответ на эти вопросы](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используется событие onscroll ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onscroll), [пример](http://learn.javascript.ru/event-onscroll)).

Comment: Как его использовать?

Comment: Если внимательно прочитать пример, который я привёл, то получится, что на событие `window.onscroll` нужно повесить обработчик (он будет вызываться при прокрутке страницы). В обработчике можно получить, сколько пользователь проскроллил (`window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop`, кроссбраузерная версия) и на основании этого производить какие-либо действия (например, перемещать дивы с картинками, как сделано по приведённой вами ссылке.)

Comment: Т.е. все упирается в то насколько мы прокрутили окно? Когда доходим до определенного значения мы выполняем опред. функцию?

Comment: В общих чертах так. Обработчик `window.onscroll` вызывается каждый раз, когда пользователь прокручивает страницу (неважно, колёсиком, стрелками или скорллбаром). То, что вы будете делать в обработчике зависит лишь от вашей фантазии.

Answer (score 0):

Этот эффект называется параллаксом. В инете можно найти массу примеров на эту тему, достаточно вбить в поисковик что-нибудь такое: [jquery parallax](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=jquery+parallax)

Comment: Думаю это не совсем паралакс, но в любом случае мне нужен именно алгоритм работы, а не плагин

Comment: алгоритм работы - двигаем фон медленнее или быстрее скролла.

Comment: Deonis, вы меня не поняли. Мне нужен не фон, а человек, под видео.) Видите как издит туда-сюда при скролле?